# To take something with a smile

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, idiomatic-language

Example: The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, but **took it with a smile** and kept going.

- Is this a phrase that is used? (In this case to mean the singer just smiled at the situation and didn't let his mistake affect him)
- And if so, would any English speaker understand it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this phrase is natural, and any proficient English speaker would understand it.

"Take", in this context, means to react to something (usually negative) in a particular way. Here's some common expressions with this sense of "take":

> She took the news of her father's death well/badly.
> Conor McGregor knows how to take a punch.

It's common to use adverbials with "with..." to describe the reaction to what is "taken", in this case, a smile.

Comment: I don't know but i think this definition is most suitable in this context — **to react to something/somebody in a particular way**, what's your opinion about this??(Oxford learner's dictionary **sense27** )

Comment: @Sam Thanks. I think that definition is better, though I don't agree that it could be reacting to someone, just something that someone does. I've edited my answer.

Comment: **I wish you'd take me seriously.** (In this example react to someone might make sense )

Comment: @Sam To "take someone seriously" is about how you think about or treat someone *in general*, not as a reaction to any particular thing

Comment: Yes, in this case (**regard** ) can be used.(I think)

Comment: @Sam Yep, that's exactly the meaning of "take" there.

Comment: There has to be what she took with a smile. Like the reaction of the audience. You don't take your own mistakes "with a smile". So, the sentence does not work meaning-wise.

Answer (score 3):

to take something with a smile is an idiomatic expression.

I*t means that something happens to you* and your response is a smile.

**However**, something has to be done to you. If you make a mistake on stage and the audience boos at you, you can take that with a smile.

Here: The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, but took it with a smile and kept going. It doesn't work.

But here: The singer was very nervous and missed a few words. *The audience booed her but she took it with a smile and kept going.*

Now, it works. This is not grammar. It's understanding idioms in context.

Comment: To me as a native AmE speaker, the original sounds fine. It feels implied that "it" is referring to "her mistakes."

Comment: @DrakeP The variety of English has no bearing  here at all. My comment would apply to any variety of English. You only take something with a smile as a reaction to something. She was booed but took it with a smile.

Answer (score 2):

I would use "carry (something) on" in this sentence.

[carry (something) on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/carry-on)(Cambridge Dictionary) to continue doing something, or to cause something to continue:

> You just have to carry on as if nothing's happened.
>
> The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, but **carried on** with a
> smile and kept going.

In the sentence

> The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, but **took it with a
> smile** and kept going.

A question arises, "what did he/she take?". The answer is unavailable in the sentence. Supposing the sentence was

> The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, insults were
> hurled at him/her, but he/she took it with a smile and kept going.

or

> The singer was very nervous and missed a few words, but took the
> attendant embarrassment with a smile and kept going.

Here the answer is available and the sentence is complete with the necessary details.

Comment: Right, she took the insults with a smile otherwise the sentence won't work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be weird to have both 'carried on' and 'kept going'? Shouldn't 'kept going' be omitted then?

Comment: Yes. Better to omit 'kept going'. Though can be used with 'kept going' too, not much harm would be done if it is used.